# How do I implement a single login interface for multiple providers in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have configured multiple external providers for Azure AD B2C. Right now, the user is forced to pick the provider that they want to authenticate with. How do I configure the system so that the user can type an email address, and the system can automatically forward the user to the proper IDP based on their email address. Similar to how the common authentication endpoint works for different azure domains in Azure AD work and student accounts.

Comment: What are examples of the external providers? Are they consumer identity providers such as Facebook etc.? Or do they include enterprise identity providers?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett mostly enterprise providers

Answer (score 5):

**Azure AD B2C does not provide any automatic IDP discovery functionality.** You can request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv)

**You can implement this yourself by leveraging the `domain_hint` feature** however this would require you keep your own table where you keep track of the username-to-IDP relationship. You'd then build your own page where the user can type his/her username, and based on this mapping table then redirect to B2C with the corresponding domain hint (for example, `domain_hint=facebook.com`)

Comment: This is similar to how Microsoft Visual Studio account validation currently determines whether the email you entered is a personal account or a business account. You'll notice that as you type in your username/email, it thinks for a bit and then redirects you to the appropriate authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea that @Saca proposed, but here's another option for consideration as well.

Have a "landing" page and let the user decide how to login, similar to how some sites will have a "login with facebook" and "login with google" links.

I would probably set a nonce value to make sure they can't login without first going to the landing page. Set a cookie so you could remember the users preference for that device/browser, and also leave an option for them to choose a different login/authentication method.

Comment: You option is fine when you have a social app that no one cares who uses it. Now tell me how this would work if you were providing services two 2 competing enterprises(and both providing IDP services) and they have to login though the same page. They could see that they are both your customers. That is a scenario that hurts a business. I could imagine 100 others where users from one organization should not know that you provide services to another organization.

Comment: I'm not sure how this approach is any different from what B2C already provides out of the box though. B2C does give you a page with buttons for each IDP...

Comment: @saca The main difference is that it allows you to set the nonce value as well as control which policy the users will use for login.

Comment: @juxhin I had not thought of the competing companies scenario. I've actually been in a scenario like that, and the previous developers had just controlled it using roles and permissions (basically, the answer from @saca). When I came onto the project, it was a permissions and roles management nightmare. It would be better to have a single instance/cluster for each customer if they each have their own IDP. It makes it easier to design when you don't have to worry (as much) about one customer gaining access to the others data.